# Cookie not sent for immediate redirect request after login with passport

Tags: express, cookies, passport.js, passport-google-oauth2

I have simple authentication setup with passport google oauth strategy. It works quite well with one exception. After getting callback, it sets a cookie (using session-cookie) and does redirect to homepage. But cookies are not sent for this immediate redirect request. If I reload again or go to any page, cookies are sent properly and I am logged in properly.

Here's the callback code for redirect

```
 router.get(
    "/google/callback",
    passport.authenticate("google", { failureRedirect: "/login" }),
    function (req, res) {
      res.redirect("/");
    }
  );
```

Any idea what might be cause???

Answer (score 0):

Found workaround for this based on what shopify is doing. Instead of redirecting I am sending below html which redirects to desired page with the cookies

```
res.contentType("text/html").send(`<html>
        <head>
          <title></title>
          <script>
            (function(){window.location = "/"})()
          </script>
        </head>
        
        <body>
          <p>Logging in...</p>
        </body>
        
        </html>`);
```